# What is the best practice to start an animation directly after the layout of an Activity was rendered?

Tags: android, layout, animation

I'm looking for a best practice pattern which helps me with the following problem.

I want to start an animation as soon as the layout of an Activity got rendered to the screen. As my animation depends of the original width and height of a View in the layout I have to start the animation some time after onResume() has finished, so I could retrieve the height and widht of the view to prepare the animation.

But I'm wondering how to trigger the animation after the layout was rendered? Are there any events I could hook into? What is the best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) should help. Also [`ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html).

I had to deal with this problem in this code [android-sliding-menu-demo](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo).