# Is the any best practice how to start transition when fragment was shown into layout of activity?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, transition

I have one activity which contains only FrameLayout for rendering fragments inside.

StartActivity.java

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);

    IntroFragment fragment = new IntroFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    ft.commit();}
```

activity_start.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
```

and one fragment which is should be rendered into StartActivity, but the problem with animated view objects by transition. I don't need animation between fragments but i need animation inside fragment after fragment rendered. There is post here on stack with same problem [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682923/what-is-the-best-practice-to-start-an-animation-directly-after-the-layout-of-an). After implementing OnGlobalLayoutListener I was able to handle the moment when some changing happens in layout (ViewGroup) which I was trying to listen. It looks like this

```
group.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.scene_root);

            final Scene scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.intro_scene_two, getApplicationContext());

            final TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
            set.setDuration(10000);
            set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL);
            set.addTarget(R.id.circle_logo);
            set.addTarget(R.id.title_logo);

            Fade fadeIn= new Fade(Fade.IN);

            ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();

            set.addTransition(fadeIn);
            set.addTransition(bounds);

            TransitionManager.go(scene2, set);


            ViewTreeObserver obs = group.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

and problem with ChangeBounds transition, when fragment is rendered, OnGlobalLayoutListener() calls and TransitionManager is changing scene from scene1 to scene2 Fade transition works pretty well except ChangeBounds. ChangeBounds doesn't work at all, like i don't have this code

```
ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();

set.addTransition(fadeIn);
```

Why it happens??

Oh sorry layout both of scenes below.

scene_one.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/circle_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:background="@drawable/circle_logo"/>
        <TextView
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/title_logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Booking" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

scene_two.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/circle_logo" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/circle_logo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Booking" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);

    scheduleStartPostponedTransition(group);

    IntroFragment fragment = new IntroFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    ft.commit();

}

private void scheduleStartPostponedTransition(final View sharedElement) {
    sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    startPostponedEnterTransition();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void startPostponedEnterTransition(){
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);

    final Scene scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.intro_scene_two, getApplicationContext());

    final TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
    set.setDuration(10000);
    set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    set.addTarget(R.id.circle_logo);
    set.addTarget(R.id.title_logo);

    Fade fadeIn = new Fade(Fade.IN);

    ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();

    set.addTransition(fadeIn);
    set.addTransition(bounds);

    TransitionManager.go(scene2, set);
}
```

I took idea and implementation from this article [Postponed Shared Element Transitions](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html)